# Pine script trend line get current price problem

Tags: pine-script, trendline

I have below script :

```
s1_first_line2 := trend_s1_line_extend ? line.new(
  sm_bag_ready ? s1T_fx : na,
  sm_bag_ready ? s1T_fy : na,
  sm_bag_ready ? s1T_tx : na,
  sm_bag_ready ? s1T_ty : na,
  extend = extend.right,
  xloc = xloc.bar_time,
  color = trend_s1_use_colors == false ? trend_s1_color_default : 
  (sTriDir == 1) ? trend_s1_line_color_up : trend_s1_line_color_dn,
  style = trend_s1_xline_style,
  width = trend_s1_xline_width) : na
//  }}}

currentLineValue = line.get_price(s1_first_line2, bar_index)
```

I cant get the current price of the trend line. it gives error:

> line.get_price must be used with  lines created using
> xloc=xloc.bar_index

How can I get above trend line current price ?

Best

Comment: Error is self explanatory -- you need to use bar_indexes instead of time values. I.e:
`xloc = xloc.bar_index` instead of    `xloc = xloc.bar_time`

Answer (score 0):

startPrice = line.get_y1(id=line1)
endPrice   = line.get_y2(id=line1)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.